# Discriminated Union label to string

Tags: f#

given the following Discriminated Union:

```ml
type A = B of string | C of int
```

How can I get the constructor B name?

```ml
A.B.ToString()
// would return something like:
val it : string = "FSI_0045+it@109-19"
// when I desire
val it : string = "B"
```

for example with this type it works:

```ml
type D = E | F

D.E.ToString();;
val it : string = "E"
```

I normally get the string name of an instance of the DU with

```ml
let stringFromDU (x: 'a) =
  match FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(x, typeof<'a>) with
  | case, _ -> case.Name
```

But in this case, I do not have an instance, I just want to serialize the label name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enable the latest language version, e.g. by passing `--langversion:preview` to FSI or setting

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

in your `.fsproj`, the following will work:

```ml
type A = B of int
let n = nameof A.B
```

Note: with F# 5 this will be supported out of the box :-)

Comment: Thank you! this should be that I want, however, I'm still not using preview as it is but unstable yet. I'm using this:
```fsharp
let rec funName =
  function
  | Patterns.NewUnionCase (x, _) -> x.Name
  | Patterns.Call (None, methodInfo, _) -> methodInfo.Name
  | Patterns.Lambda (_, expr) -> funName expr
  | _ -> failwith "Unexpected input"
<@ A.B @> |> funName
```

I'll switch to `nameof` after F# 5 is out. I found this a bit bad as I have to provide a fail function -.-

Comment: @CodingEdgar You can use the preview features with current 4.7... for me, no issues so far :-)

Comment: I'll give it a shot and get back to you if everything compiles, thank you!

Comment: Used your approach, everything compiled and worked like a charm, thank you.

Comment: copilot suggested the `FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<'T>) |> Array.map (fun caseInfo -> caseInfo.Name)` on the 3rd try when asked the same question (just look at the date of this comment...)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `FSharpValue` from `FSharp.Reflection` namespace in your example. Note that there's another class in that library for handling scenarios where you want to work with types only, `FSharpType`.

```
let cases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<A>)
```

Outside of unions, it also provides helpers for other operations on F# native types.

Comment: Yes, I do use this one to convert from string to DU, but I cannot get the name of a DU case with this one, like the desired example above, I think.

Comment: It can give you names of all the cases, but you're right, it won't let you go from a union case constructor to its name. Quotations would be the right tool here, the way you use them now.